# How is the given linear CFL NL-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-theory

I wanted to know how this language: `L1={a^nb^n|n≥0}`

is NL-complete?

I know that this language is in L, so therefore it is in NL too. But, how is it NL-hard?

Comment: & who told you that, where did you hear it? doesnt sound immediately plausible (its probably too simple), but to disprove it might not be so simple. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL-complete) has info on basic NL complete languages, st-connectivity is the std known one.